# What is faster traverse through record or large field?

Tags: mysql, database

Situation: I'm trying to create a page which has members that are allowed to view it's content and each member is defined by an ID. To access the information for the page I want to make sure the user is a member of the page.

Question: Is it faster to have one large record that has to be traversed through to look up IDs or create one field that's indexed that have several (billions) of records but that all very small?

Comment: Create a junction table and connect the user with the page via their IDs, using foreign keys. One user can most likely view more pages, and one page can be accessed by many users, therefore many to many is what you're after. If you're after billions, make sure you have sufficient RAM for your database.

Comment: Thanks that's what I was wondering.

Comment: "one large record that has to be traversed through to look up IDs" please don't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rdms servers like MySQL are optimized for the lookup of a few short records from among many.  If you structure your data that way and index it correctly, you'll get decent performance.

On the other hand, long lists of data requiring linear search will not scale up well.

By the way, plan for tens of millions of records, not billions. If you actually need to handle billions, you'll probably have the resources to scale up your system. In the meantime RAM and disk storage are still on a Moore's-law cost curve, even if CPUs aren't.

Answer (score 0):

That scenario would typically be implemented with three tables. A simplified version would look something like this:

`users(id, name, password, ... )`
`pages(id, title, .... )`
`page_access(user_id, page_id, permission)`

where `user_id` and `page_id` are references to the `users` and `pages` tables respectively. In your application you would then check the current page and user against the `page_access` table to see if permission should be granted or denied.

MySQL has no trouble processing millions upon millions of well indexed rows, so long as you have sufficient hardware powering it.  You want to aim for [normalised data](http://www.devshed.com/c/a/mysql/an-introduction-to-database-normalization/), not cramming everything into a single row in a single table.